# how to call C function in python without cdll

Tags: python, c, wrapper

I am trying to create a simple script to test calling a C function in python script.

There are solution that using ctypes (load cdll wrapper) but for my application that i will load those script (using micro python interpreter) on to a MCU and it wont have any system file.

Is there other way to call C function in python ?

thanks

sample code if using ctypes :

C:

```
int our_function(int num_numbers, int *numbers) {
    int i;
    int sum;
    for (i = 0; i < num_numbers; i++) {
        sum += numbers[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

compile with gcc first

python:

```
import ctypes
import sum

_sum = ctypes.CDLL('libsum.so')
_sum.our_function.argtypes = (ctypes.c_int, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))

def our_function(numbers):
    global _sum
    num_numbers = len(numbers)
    array_type = ctypes.c_int * num_numbers
    result = _sum.our_function(ctypes.c_int(num_numbers), array_type(*numbers))
    return int(result)
```

Comment: I don't understand your restriction, but you should always use `cffi` (in one of its 4 modes) rather than ctypes.

Comment: What is "python script"? Is that something like JavaScript (which has nothing to do with Java)?

Comment: python script is just my way of saying python code. Sorry if that confusing